# How is the Add-In search feature in Sparx Enterprise Architect used and what is its purpose?

Tags: enterprise-architect

There appears to be very little documentation regarding the Add-In search feature and how it can be used to better provide search results. How can it be used and what is its purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Add-In search, rather than searching the database itself, calls a function in an Add-In. The function must return the search results in the XML format described in the help file.

Since Add-Ins are written in a proper programming language (usually C#) and have access to the Object Model API, it is far easier to implement an arbitrarily complex search in an Add-In than in an SQL query.

The disadvantage is that writing an Add-In is a much bigger job than putting together a query.

Comment: Thanks Uffe. Does this mean that the Add-In is only used when accessing the Object Model API?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean there. The Object Model API is used by the Add-In (as is the Add-In Model API). It is provided by the Interop.EA DLL, which is part of the regular EA installation.

Comment: Sorry. I meant that would I only use the Add-In if I wanted to access the Object Model API?

Comment: The Add-In has to use the Object Model API to access the model stuff but it can also use any other API:s you like, such as MS Word, Subversion, ODBC, the file system, sockets, etc etc. So by writing an Add-In you can add any functionality to EA, not just modelling enhancements.